# Do villages need to be prosperous to start a great project?

Tags: reus

When attempting the Divided Planet development, much of my work was preventing the villages from destroying each other due primarily from their greed from failed Great Projects. Now I am looking at the Mass Production development and wondering how I could prevent six villages once again from murdering each other. If I can control when villages start their great projects, I could avoid the World Wars and stick to small land skirmishes.

I have noticed that if I leave a village with very little, they tend not to start a great project even if they have an upgraded project.

What causes a village to start a great project? Does the village require a certain level of prosperity to start the great project? How much?